# Происхождение названия "Волотова".

Tags: этимология

В городе, где я живу есть микрорайон «Волотова», чьё название происходит от деревни, некогда располагавшейся на месте современных застроек.  Есть сведения, что в Сибири жил народ волотов-великанов, ныне исчезнувший, возможно, название произошло отсюда, но я не уверен, т.к. от нас до Сибири несколько тысяч километров. Буду очень благодарен за сведения, которые вы можете предоставить по поводу происхождения этого названия.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько мне удалось узнать, "волот" - это одно из древнерусских синонимов слова "богатырь". Видимо, отсюда и название.

Answer (score 1):

Волоты, по поверьям, — некогда населявшие землю гиганты- богатыри. По сообщению Ф. Буслаева, велеты или волоты, чудаки — < первобытные жители Сибири, от которых будто бы остались курганы».

В. Даль так характеризует связанные с волотами поверья: волот — «гигант, великан, могучан, магыт, могут, вёлетень (Юг), богатырь, человек необычайного роста, а иногда и силы. В волотах сказочных, в богатырях, сила соединяется с ростом и дородством: остатки их народ видит в костях допотопных животных, а в Сибири говорит, что целый народ ВОЛОТОВ заживо ушел в землю» <Даль, 1880>.

Хотя само название «волот» отмечено не повсеместно, образ исполина-богатыря — один из самых популярных в крестьянских поверьях и рассказах. 
http://svetoslav.moy.su/forum/19-63-1

Comment: Здесь интересная информация  о Волотовой горе http://slav-drevnosti.livejournal.com/44247.html

Comment: Слова **"велет"** и **"велетень"** ([вЭлэт], [вЭлэтэнь]), что означает *великан*, употребляются не только в Сибири, но и на Украине.

@Сашка-дурак, а до Украины от вас тоже тысячи километров? :-)

Comment: Нет. До Украины от нас 40км.

Comment: Ваш ответ, София, видится наиболее полным и интересным. А вы не могли бы проанализировать, как происходит само слово "волотова": собирательное существительное, наподобе - брат-братва, либо это слово, отвечающее на вопрос "чья?", как Волотова гора?

Comment: Думаю, что собирательного суффикса "В" в названии "Волотова" нет.Географические названия местностей  относятся к м., ср. или ж. роду, а также к мн. числу,  и образуются по соответствующему образцу: основа  мотивирующего сущ. + суффикс прилагат. + окончание.  Таким образом,  населенный пункт, связанный с волотами, может называться Волотов, Волот, Волотово, и в нашем случае -  Волот/ов/а.

Comment: В то же время такая  структура названия встречается не часто. Обычно при наличии суффикс «ОВ» мы имеем сущ. м. или ср. рода, а в случае ж.рода добавляется суффикс К: Глотовка, Ермоловка,  Коржевка. С другими суффиксами названия ж.рода вполне обычны: Барвиха, Потапиха, Какорма, Шемурша, Адоевщина и др.

Answer (score 0):

Волоты - люди сильной и могучей воли .. И неважно карлики они или великаны , за правое дело стоят или на лево повело их ..